# How to import a dependecy's dependency?

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

I'm coding a web app and I need to reuse a function which is included as a dependency of one of my dependencies. I know how to import the main dependency:

```
import {DataTable} from "simple-datatables";
```

But how can I import one of its dependencies? I already tried this one but didn't work:

```
import {DataTable} from "simple-datatables/helpers";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to import?

Comment: I want to import the function "createElement" located in simple-datatables/helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import an exported function like this

```
import { createElement } from "simple-datatables/src/helpers";
```

**Note:** the file helpers.js is into the folder `src/`

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Standard_Import)

Comment: npm compiling log:  ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                    
                                                           
This dependency was not found:                             
                                                           
* simple-datatables/helpers.js in ./assets/js/sigmetCorp.js

Comment: @Nestor I tested this module on my project. You need to add src/ into the path. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import {DataTable} from "~simple-datatables/helpers";
```

Comment: This wont work because DataTable, which I already imported Ok isn't in Helpers, what I want to import is a function in Helpers file

Comment: please post the helper file

Comment: @NikkoKhresna Founded on [github](https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables/blob/master/src/helpers.js)